# Warning: passing argument 2 of ‘type_specifier’ from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

Can someone please explain these errors? I don't have a multidimensional array so I don't understand how I'm getting this error.

```
main.c:291: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘type_specifier’ from incompatible pointer type
main.c:263: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
main.c:291: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘type_specifier’ from incompatible pointer type
```

Here is my code. I call program() from main then I try to call declaration_list() from program().

```
void declaration_list(char *strings_line_tokens[], int *big_boy_counter, int *lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter)
{
    int cmp_str1 = 0;
    int cmp_str2 = 0;
    int cmp_str3 = 0;
    printf("declaration_list().\n");
    cmp_str1 = strcmp("int", strings_line_tokens[*lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
    cmp_str2 = strcmp("float", strings_line_tokens[*lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
    cmp_str3 = strcmp("void", strings_line_tokens[*lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
    if(cmp_str1 == 0 || cmp_str2 == 0 || cmp_str3 == 0)
    {
        declaration(strings_line_tokens, &big_boy_counter, &lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
    }
    //declaration_prime();
    //declaration_list();
}

void program(char *strings_line_tokens[], int *big_boy_counter, int *lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter)
{
    int cmp_str1 = 0;
    int cmp_str2 = 0;
    int cmp_str3 = 0;
    printf("In program().\n");
    cmp_str1 = strcmp("int", strings_line_tokens[*lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
    cmp_str2 = strcmp("float", strings_line_tokens[*lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
    cmp_str3 = strcmp("void", strings_line_tokens[*lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter]);
    if(cmp_str1 == 0 || cmp_str2 == 0 || cmp_str3 == 0)
    {
        declaration_list(strings_line_tokens, &big_boy_counter, &lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `declaration_list(strings_line_tokens, big_boy_counter, lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);` instead of `declaration_list(strings_line_tokens, &big_boy_counter, &lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);`

Comment: @CoolGuy 
 
I wanna increment `lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter` and decrement `big_boy_counter`. So wouldn't I need to pass the address? Or is there some kind of decaying going on? Decaying always confuses me.

Comment: There is no "decay" here. Try the suggestion. I think it'll probably work.

Comment: @CoolGuy Thank you :). It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declaration_list(strings_line_tokens, &big_boy_counter, &lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
```

In this `big_boy_counter` is already an `int *` , but you pass it's address . But you function expects an `int *` .

Also the 3rd argument you need to pass `int *` , but as `lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter` is also `int *` and you pass it's address.

Just pass `big_boy_counter` and `lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter` to it in function call's. Like this -

```
declaration_list(strings_line_tokens, big_boy_counter, lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter);
```

Comment: I wanna increment `lower_bound_of_big_boy_counter` and decrement  `big_boy_counter`. So wouldn't I need to pass the address? Or is there some kind of decaying going on? Decaying always confuses me.

Comment: @rockstar797 Decaying takes place with arrays when passed to function . But not with these pointers.

Comment: @rockstar797  Here pointer contains address of value and you pass it , No , need to pass address of pointer.

Comment: @rockstar797  Glad to help :)